# Can a gas dryer leak CO thru a second dryer via a y vent connection?

Tags: safety, dryer, carbon-monoxide

We have a second stackable electric dyer on the first floor that is vented via a Y vent connection from our primary gas dryer in the basement.  The electric dryer actually gets warm when the gas dryer runs.  Is there any danger of carbon monoxide escaping into the house thru the electric dryer vent?

Comment: the question can never be answered `no` ... the question is similar to `could I get sick tomorrow?`

Comment: It is possible.  You have a second outlet(into the house) if vent ever gets blocked.  Even without blockage can be letting gas in.  Get a CO alarm.

Comment: We have one near by

Comment: To be safe would remove the Y joint and use a separate vent for the electric dryer.  Electric dryers only put out very moist warm air.

Comment: Is it normal to have a dryer vent that's this long?  Seems like a bad idea to me, separate from the gas... longer dryer vent = hard to clean = lint fire...

Comment: Does your CO alarm ever go off? When it's placed close to the electric drier?

Comment: Your gas dryer is not working correctly if it is making CO. That would be dangerous , get it repaired .

Answer (score 8):

### Yeah, definitely

Any backpressure or restriction in the dryer vent duct beyond the wye piece *will* cause backdrafting into the house via the second dryer vent in your situation.  Given that a gas dryer is blowing combustion exhaust out its vent, this is a bad situation, especially considering that lint-induced dryer duct restrictions are inevitable.  In order to solve this, you'll need to give the electric dryer its own vent or replace it with a condensing dryer, preferably a heat pump model.  (IMC 504.10 and 504.11 require a continuous or interlocked exhaust booster fan of the appropriate type, but are not intended to be used in a SFR context where the required maintenance cannot be guaranteed.)

Answer (score 1):

If your gas dryer is making CO , you have bigger problems than a "Y" connection. How did you measure CO? Are you getting bad headaches when the gas dryer is running ? If you have any objective fact indicating CO is being produced , do not use the dryer until it is corrected.

Comment: OP did not indicate any actual presence of CO. The statement is " Is there any danger..." Gas dryer venting is designed to handle CO *just in case* and the concern is *if there is any CO, will the combined venting allow it to get into the house*.